# JS scroll to next element (hammer.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hammer.js

I got this in my functions.js

```
$('.cta').click(function(){

var curActive = $('.side-nav').find('.is-active'),
    curPos = $('.side-nav').children().index(curActive),
    lastItem = $('.side-nav').children().length - 1,
    nextPos = lastItem;

updateNavs(lastItem);
updateContent(curPos, nextPos, lastItem);
```

});

How can I use .cta class to scroll to **next** or **previous** element/item instead of last. Is it possible to also set it to use div id?

I'm playing with this theme:
[Global](http://demo.themefisher.com/others/global/)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$('.cta').click(function() {
    let __nav = $('.side-nav'),
        __current = __nav.find('.is-active'),
        want_next = $(this).hasClass('next'),
        current_active = __nav.children().index(__current),
        next_active = (want_next) ? current_active + 1 : current_active - 1;

    next_active = (next_active > __nav.children().length) ? __nav.children().length : ((next_active < 0) ? 0 : next_active);

    __current.removeClass('is-active');
    $(__nav.children()[next_active]).addClass('is-active');

});
```

[Working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/f6hdky5m/)

Comment: Thanks, but that is not working for me. I'm trying to use .cta class on button or link to trigger a new page

Comment: @WwelsonDdolb And what's not working? You just have to add the next class into the class list of the mentioned link / button, that's all.